# Mongoose Nest JS - Best way to create references between two schemas?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

I have two schemas: `User` and `BankDetails`.

```js
// User Schema
@Schema()
export class User extends Document {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  username: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  email: string;
}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

```js
// BankDetails schema
@Schema()
export class BankDetails extends Document {
  @Prop({ required: true })
  accountName: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  bankName: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  accountNumber: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  bsb: string;
}

export const BankDetailsSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(BankDetails);
```

I want to create reference between these two schemas.
What I normally do is, inside the `BankDetails` schema, I add a userId property that references to the user associated with that bank details document. Something like this:

```js
@Schema()
export class BankDetails extends Document {
 // ...previously defined properties here

  @Prop({ 
    ref: 'User',
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
  })  // Reference to User schema
  userId: User;
}
```

My question is, is this method okay or is there any best way of doing this?

**An user can have multiple bank details.**